# Using SSIS execute process task to run a batch file

Tags: batch-file, ssis, psexec

I was tasked to execute a batch file using SSIS "execute process task".
FYI,The batch file(named test.bat) uses PsExec command to call a runthisboy.bat file on a remote webserver to refresh the appPool. Here is what I wrote in the test.bat:

```
psexec -d -i -s \\webserver1 -u domainName\myID -p myPassword "C:\Documents\runthisboy.bat"
```

After I run the SSIS package, there is an error message shows up:

> [Execute Process Task] Error: In Executing "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" "/c C:\Users\myName\Desktop\test.bat" at "", The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0".

But if I use this SSIS package to run other .bat file, like:

```
xcopy /d /y "C:\Users\myName\Desktop\sample.txt" "C:\documents"
```

It runs without any problems.

If anyone can give me some clue about what is happening here, I will be so thankful!

Comment: Where is C:\Users\myName\Desktop\test.bat? `wmic process call create notepad.exe` is windows way of doing it.

Comment: @Noodles the test.bat is on my computer, not on the server side.

Comment: PSExec is running on the server. Therefore it is looking on that server in your profile (if it exists). Try `\\YourComputername\C$\Users\myname\desktop\test.bat`. `C$` is a hidden share (`$`) for admin use. Each drive has one.

Comment: @Noodles I tried but result in same error message : (